# Balancing Two NICs

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, network-adapter

I play a lot of online games, and having a constant, uninterrupted, internet connection is crucial.

My idea:

Connect both NICs in the machine to the same router.

My question:

Will this effectively cover myself so that if one method hiccups or momentarily drops, the other will maintain a constant connection? or will it still drop connections while it switches from one NIC to the other?

Comment: If there is a connectivity issue within your network, that is worse than the performance and reliability of the internet, then there are likely to be better options than dual nics.  Like replacing cables or nics (your question suggests you are confident that the router is fine).  Was there an experience that led to this question?

Comment: I haven't worked out the complete source of the issue, but I already have two nics on my Mobo, so I wondered if it would help.

Comment: It seems likely you'd hit convergence issues with teaming nics - it would seem worth eliminating likely candidates.  Have you tried using the second nic exclusively with a new cable for a while?

Answer (score 3):

what you want is a NIC Team or Bridge.  Both technologies basically allow both your adapters to act as a single unit.

This would definitely help you in the event that one NIC has a minor problem, however - be aware that this obviously wouldn't help if your internet connection or router has a hiccup.

Assuming both of your Network adapters support this, it should be fairly simple to implement.

Given the choice of both technologies, I would recommend you setup a NIC Team.

It is definitely worth googling to see if your hardware supports teaming - if not, setup a windows bridged connection.  [This short guide](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/create-network-bridge#1TC=windows-7) will talk you through the process

Hope this helps

Comment: This is actually worth looking into. even if it doesnt solve the problem, extra redundancy never hurts.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't it require a special configuration on the switch side as well?

Comment: @EliadTech, not necessarily.  There are fault tolerant switch-independent modes that can be implemented client-side only.  If you are looking for increased throughput then the switch/device you connect to must be configured.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which system you are talking about. I have looked at this issue under winodws. It is actually worse then you think. If one NIC looses the connection, your application will loose the connection and will not automatically switch to another nick. In most cases you can only resolve the problem by restarting application/game or re-establishing connection.

Comment: Yeah, I'm working in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Given your tags I you are talking about a wireless network.  I suspect this will not help as much as you are hoping.

If you just added to identical wireless nics and connected to the same AP, then the issues that cause loss of connectivity are just as likely to connect both the radios on your client.  You wouldn't improve anything

If you really needed redundant connectivity, you would really want to run the two nics on separate wifi networks on separate frequencies.  Perhaps you would connect one to a 5ghz network and the other to a 2.4ghz network, that way interference on one interface is not very likely to affect the other.

Your next challenge is that most desktop versions of Windows don't support teaming natively, and very few drivers support any kind of teaming of wifi interfaces.  Without bonding at layer two, this would all be pointless.

Of course this all assumes that your problem is something about your wireless link.  If problems you have are upstream from the wireless ap/router, then the above would be wasted.

In any case, if you are using wireless as your tags suggest, the far better solution would be to run a piece of wire.